# Sign PKCS10 Certificate in Java

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I need to sign PKCS10 request by other, trusted certificate, and actualy I can't find examples for that. I think examples can be on http://bouncycastle.org/wiki but, that page dosn't work.

For my opinion that would be a function like:

```
public static X509Certificate signCertificateRequest(X509Certificate trustedCertificate, 
             PrivateKey privateKey, PKCS10 certificateRequest)
   {
     //signing code
   }
```

Can you give me examples for using PKCS10 and X509Certificate in the same code?

Comment: You are aware that if you're operating a CA, you'll want to do more than just sign a request? (In particular, you'll want to keep track of what certificates you think you've signed, and what of those you think are valid and what are invalid.)

Comment: @donal-fellows Yes, I know. Actually I find good examples for all operations what I need, except that one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334468/java-sign-certificate-programaticaly-without-bc

Answer (score 1):

With help from [Sign CSR using Bouncy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230330/sign-csr-using-bouncy-castle) :

```
 private org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate signCertificateSigningRequest(
    JcaPKCS10CertificationRequest jcaPKCS10CertificationRequest,
    KeyPair keyPair, X509Certificate serverCertificate)
      throws IOException, OperatorCreationException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException
  {
    // Signing CSR
    AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder()
      .find("SHA1withRSA");

    X509v3CertificateBuilder certificateBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(
        serverCertificate, 
        new BigInteger("1"), //serial
        new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
        new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30L * 365L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L),
        jcaPKCS10CertificationRequest.getSubject(),
        jcaPKCS10CertificationRequest.getPublicKey()
    /*).addExtension(
        new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.35"),
        false,
        new AuthorityKeyIdentifier(...)*/
    ).addExtension(
            new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.19"),
            false,
            new BasicConstraints(false) // true if it is allowed to sign other certs
    ).addExtension(
            new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.15"),
            true,
            new X509KeyUsage(
                X509KeyUsage.digitalSignature |
                    X509KeyUsage.nonRepudiation   |
                    X509KeyUsage.keyEncipherment  |
                    X509KeyUsage.dataEncipherment));

    AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter =
          PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
    //ContentSigner sigGen = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId, digAlgId).build(asymmetricKeyParameter);
    ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").build(keyPair.getPrivate());


    X509CertificateHolder x509CertificateHolder = certificateBuilder.build(sigGen);
    org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate eeX509CertificateStructure =
      x509CertificateHolder.toASN1Structure();
    return eeX509CertificateStructure;
  }

  private X509Certificate readCertificateFromASN1Certificate(
    org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate eeX509CertificateStructure,
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory)
    throws IOException, CertificateException {
    // Read Certificate
    InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(eeX509CertificateStructure.getEncoded());
    X509Certificate signedCertificate =
      (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(is1);
    return signedCertificate;
  }

  private String convertCertificateToPEM(X509Certificate signedCertificate) throws IOException {
    StringWriter signedCertificatePEMDataStringWriter = new StringWriter();
    JcaPEMWriter pemWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(signedCertificatePEMDataStringWriter);
    pemWriter.writeObject(signedCertificate);
    pemWriter.close();
    log.info("PEM data:");
    log.info("" + signedCertificatePEMDataStringWriter.toString());
    return signedCertificatePEMDataStringWriter.toString();
  }
```