# package sun.security.pkcs10 is not visible and package sun.security.x509 is not visible while migrating from Java 8 to Java 17

Tags: java, java-8, java-17

While migrating my application from Java 8 to Java 17, I'm facing error

> package sun.security.pkcs10 is not visible package sun.security.x509
> is not visible

Following is the code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
private static byte[] encodeAndSignRequest(KeyPair keyPair, Signature signature,
        X500Principal principal) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`enter code here`
    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outStream, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    sun.security.pkcs10.PKCS10 pkcs10 = new sun.security.pkcs10.PKCS10(keyPair.getPublic());
    pkcs10.encodeAndSign(sun.security.x509.X500Name.asX500Name(principal), signature);
    pkcs10.print(printStream);
    return outStream.toByteArray();
}
```

As it is getting the public key and trying to encode that key based on the PKCS10 which is not present in Java 17, The above method is throwing an exception as PKCS is downgraded and removed in Java 17. What should be used over here to solve this issue?

Comment: Even in Java 8 you shouldn't have used those classes directly. BTW: those classes were not removed or deprecated, they have just been made inaccessible to code that shouldn't have been using them in the first place.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Your comment makes it sound like they did something illegal which is ridiculous. OP is not making an assertion that 'sun.security should remain supported in JDK17' (in which case you'd have a point: The sun.* packages explicitly disclaim continuing support). Their question is completely fair and 'you should build a time machine, go back in time, and yell at your past selves for messing up' is not an appropriate response.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Even in the past, using classes from `sun.*` was explicitly not recommended, which is why they are no longer exported.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Mark is right. Sun has stated long ago that classes from `sun.*` and `com.sun.*` could be changed or deleted at any time, and you shouldn't use those. Oracle stuck to that policy.

Comment: I never said he was wrong. I said it's inappropriate to 'answer' a question that __already__ includes the statement of 'What should be used here', i.e. already is willing to use a different library, with: "You messed up in using it in the first place". This is one of those textbook cases of 'SO is mean'. There is no need for this. If OP starts whining about 'But how can I use this sun.* stuff on JDK17', I'll be right there with you. But they didn't.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61149455/access-sun-security-x509-in-jdk-11-without-modules) and the linked ones might help you find the alternate solution you might be looking for.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I didn't post an answer, I posted a comment to point an incorrect assumption in the question (_"as PKCS is downgraded and removed in Java 17."_). The `sun.security.pkcs10` class only exists in Java due to the `keytool` commandline utility.

Answer (score -3):

[*BouncyCastle*](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/pkcs/PKCS10CertificationRequest.html) has various PKCS10 capable classes. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155024/sign-pkcs10-certificate-in-java) for an example. You'll need to rewrite your code a bit, they haven't copied the `sun.security.*` API.

Comment: This "answer" seems more like a comment to me. Why did you post this as an answer?

Comment: @rzwitserloot That is a "link-only" answer. Just pointing to a library without showing how to use it is not considered an answer.